# EAP 7.X ClassNotFoundException during migration

Tags: wildfly, jboss7.x

I am migrating an application to EAP 7.x, My project structure is

```
-Ear  
  -War
  -Ejb Jar
```

I am getting ClassNotFoundException, those classes are in the jar. The below is the stack trace. All exception showing in the classes that are in the ejb jar.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.ttt.xxx.ejb.sessionbeans.messagebroker.MessageHandlerSessionBeanCHI with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.xxx-dev-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.ejbModule-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" from Service Module Loader
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:78)
at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:143)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ttt/xxx/ejb/sessionbeans/messagebroker/MessageHandlerSessionBeanCHI$xmlException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
... 13 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ttt.xxx.ejb.sessionbeans.messagebroker.MessageHandlerSessionBeanCHI$xmlException from [Module "deployment.xxx-dev-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.ejbModule-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
... 18 more
```

The jar packing with ear is.

```
    META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
aopalliance-1.0.jar
axiom-api-1.2.12.jar
axiom-impl-1.2.12.jar
axis2-adb-1.6.1.jar
axis2-adb-codegen-1.6.1.jar
axis2-codegen-1.6.1.jar
axis2-kernel-1.6.1.jar
axis2-transport-http-1.6.1.jar
axis2-transport-local-1.6.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-lang-2.3.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.5.5.jar
displaytag-1.2.jar
displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar
displaytag-portlet-1.2.jar
ejbModule-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.2.jar
geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.6.jar
geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.jar
geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar
httpcore-4.0.jar
itext-1.3.jar
jaxen-1.1.1.jar
jcl104-over-slf4j-1.4.2.jar
jsr311-api-1.0.jar
jstl-1.1.2.jar
log4j.xml
META-INF/application.xml
META-INF/jboss-app.xml
META-INF/jboss-deployment-struture.xml
xxx-dev-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.war
neethi-3.0.1.jar
poi-3.2-FINAL.jar
slf4j-api-1.4.2.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.4.2.jar
spring-asm-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
standard-1.1.2.jar
woden-api-1.0M9.jar
woden-impl-commons-1.0M9.jar
woden-impl-dom-1.0M9.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar
XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar
META-INF/maven/
xMETA-INF/maven/com.ttt.xxx/ear/
META-INF/maven/com.ttt.xxx/ear/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.ttt.xxx/ear/pom.properties
```

Please help to solve, I am suspecting issue is coming due to wrong class loading. But i am not able to fix it.

Comment: Where is `com.ttt.xxx.ejb.sessionbeans.messagebroker.MessageHandlerSessionBeanCHI` located? I don't really follow the above listing, but if those JAR's aren't in the `EAR/lib` directory they definitely should be.

Comment: com.ttt.xxx.ejb.sessionbeans.messagebroker.MessageHandlerSessionBeanCHI in ejb jar file.

Comment: You might want to double check that because the CNFE is being thrown in `ejbModule-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. If that's the EJB JAR you're referring to there must be some other kind of issue.

Comment: Yes you are correct.The CNFE is thrown in ejbModule-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.     My application.xml is here           
 <application>
  <display-name>ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>mssweb-dev-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/mssapp</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>ejbModule-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>

Comment: The important thing to know is where the `com.ttt.xxx.ejb.sessionbeans.messagebroker.MessageHandlerSessionBeanCHI` is located.